# Sort a GridView thats bound to a Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I've got a GridView that I populate using a Linq query

```
var usersToApprove = from rl in QVDash.Permisisons
                           join u in QVDash.Userson rl.UserId equals u.UserId
                           join d in QVDash.Dashboards on rl.DashboardId equals d.DashboardId 
                           where (u.ApprovedBy == approverId || isGod)
                           select new
                           {
                               PermissionId = rl.PermissionId,
                               Name = u.Name,
                               Area = u.Area,
                               Dashboard = d.DashboardName,
                               OpUnit = rl.Operational_Unit,
                               Cost_Centre = rl.Cost_Centre,
                               Fund = rl.Fund,
                               Project = rl.Project,
                               Approver = (from a in QVDash.Users where a.UserId == u.UserId && a.UserId == u.ApprovedBy select a.Name).FirstOrDefault()
                           };

        grd_CurrentUsers.DataSource = usersToApprove ;
        grd_CurrentUsers.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "PermissionId" };
        grd_CurrentUsers.DataBind();
```

This however presents an issue, where the GridView will not allow sorting.

I've tried a few options that I've found which resort to building a custom sorting function, however I've found this to be sketchy at best, which issues such as: Only one way sorting, Paging resets sort etc.

What I'm wanting to know is if there is a better way to do this.

I know that binding the gridview to a datasource takes care of the sorting issue, however I don't know how to bind my Linq to a data source.  Is it possible?

Comment: How is the above code called?

Comment: BTW, there is no need to put things like " (ASP.NET C#)" in your title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @John  I do that because i've seen people get the wrong responses because people don't look at the tags

Comment: since people can use the tags to filter out questions they're not interested in, and to highlight questions with the right tags, I suggest you use the tags instead of the title. The title has neither of those two features.

Comment: @Nix  What I was doing is calling it from a few places as a method, the method then ran the above code, and bound the output to the gridview with .DataSouce and .DataBind. I did it this way to update it when I made changes to the gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out with the sorting code from this site
http://forums.asp.net/t/1368247.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the LinqDataSource control? Check out this link. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx

Key part: "To handle custom query scenarios you can implement an event handler to handle the "Selecting" event on the  control.  Within this event handler you can write whatever code you want to retrieve a data model result."

This allows you to sort, page, etc, with your custom LINQ query.

Comment: I'm using Linq to Entities :/